# Tikz picture with nodes and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \newcount\tmpnum
\def\storedata#1#2{\tmpnum=0 \edef\tmp{\string#1}\storedataA#2\end}
\def\storedataA#1{\advance\tmpnum by1
   \ifx\end#1\else
      \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\tmpnum\endcsname{#1}%
      \expandafter\storedataA\fi
}
\def\getdata[#1]#2{\csname data:\string#2:#1\endcsname}

\storedata\moredata{{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,
                semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=none,text=black]

  \def \n {4}
  \def \radius {1.3cm}
  \def \margin {5} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

  \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  {
    \node[state] (\getdata[\s]\moredata) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+45}:\radius) {$\getdata[\s]\moredata$};
  }

  \path (A) edge              node {} (B);
  \path (B) edge              node {} (A);
  \path (A) edge              node {} (C);
  \path (D) edge              node {} (B);
  \path (D) edge              node {} (C);
  \path (C) edge              node {} (A);
  \path (C) edge              node {} (B);
  \path (C) edge              node {} (D);
  \path (C) edge[loop right]  node {} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have several questions:

1. What does `shorten >= 1 pt` do?
2. What does `node distance` do?
3. What does `margin` do?
4. What does `stealth` do?
5. When I compile the document, there seems to be a lot of space between the tip of the arrow and the letter. How do I change that?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: For Questions 1-4 you can look into the [pgf manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf). For example you can find `shorten` on page 162. If you want an answer for question 5 you should add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Usually you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question".

Comment: If you're unsure what a particular option does, you can comment it with a `%`, or change the length that comes with it. Then, see what changed on the drawing. If nothing has changed, it probably means you don't need that option.

Comment: (i) your MWE doesn't work (ii) `shorten >= 1 ` make line shorter on destination side for 1pt (iii) `node distance` determine distance between nodes in image (if you not override it) (iv) `margin` as option of `geometry` package determine text margins on page, in your code is defined for unknown purposes (see (i)),  (v) `stealth` is one of among predetermined  arrow heads.

Comment: @dexteritas `shorten >` is not a good example: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/388/.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Both variants are in the manual: `/tikz/shorten >= 〈dimension〉` and `/tikz/shorten <= 〈dimension〉` with the comment: "Works like `shorten >`, but for the start." You can also find them with CTRL+F and they are in the index on page 879.

Comment: @dexteritas You read an old version of pgfmanual. The latest version (v3.0.1a) is [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).